# How to determine if a rectangle was intersected by any other rectangle in a form C# not XNA

Tags: c#, .net

I want to determine if a rectangle is intersected by any other rectangle in the form in C# not in XNA.

So here's a scenario. Rectangles A and B change location randomly (using a timer) in the form while Rectangle C is static. None of the rectangles should know about each other so

```
if (RectA.IntersectsWith(RectB))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("KAPOW");
            }
```

is not ideal...

Cheers for any help you can give me.

Comment: Some code needs to know about both, right? So why can't that code execute the code as shown?

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with System.Drawing.Rectangle.InterectsWith() method?

Comment: because the rectangles should NOT know about each others existence...so it as to be compared to any rectangle no 'a' rectangle